# Run a terminal command recursively for all files in a folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, recursion, terminal, pdfbox

I am working on a problem that requires me to extract text from a pdf. I am using pdfbox in order to do so. So, I run this command in the terminal (linux ubuntu):

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.7.jar ExtractText [path leading to file here]
```

and everything works. However, I want to do this recursively for thousands of files in a particular directory, so I don't have to manually plug in the pdf path every time. I would appreciate any solution that's either from the terminal or a script.

Comment: Two words: `man find` ))

Comment: `for i in *.pdf; do java .... ExtractText $i; done`, basically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `find` command:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.7.jar ExtractText {} \;
```

Comment: For some other use I need to give the /path/to/directory in the end, how it is possible?

Comment: Put `/path/to/directory` before `\;`.

Comment: @supremum I suggest you ask a new question rather than try to solve this in comments.

Comment: @supremum And don't assume that the readers know what `audacious` is. I don't.